# ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException rxjava setVisibiltiy through rxjava

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java2, android-runonuithread

Hi Everyone currently I have a problem with threads in RXJava. I wanna set visible through rxjava but android throw me a this exception

> "ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException"

```
Disposable disposable = Single.concat(
            getClearStorageObservable()
                    .doOnError(Timber::e)
                    .onErrorResumeNext(Single.just(false)),
            getDownloadObservable())
            .subscribeOn(schedulers().io())
            .observeOn(schedulers().ui())
            .delay(DELAY_VALUE,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(status -> hideErrorInformation(),
                    error -> showErrorInformation()
            );
    disposables().add(disposable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You applied `delay` after `observeOn` so the flow was switched away from the UI thread. Drop `observeOn` and reorder the flow as follows:

```java
Disposable disposable = Single.concat(
        getClearStorageObservable()
                .doOnError(Timber::e)
                .onErrorResumeNext(Single.just(false)),
        getDownloadObservable())
        .subscribeOn(schedulers().io())
        .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, schedulers().ui())
        .delay(DELAY_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS, schedulers().ui())
        .subscribe(status -> hideErrorInformation(),
                error -> showErrorInformation()
        );
disposables().add(disposable);
```

Comment: Thanks you bro :)  idk, that i can set scheduler in delay and timeout . I have extra question to you why are you remove observeOn. Averybody told me that subscribe on is a pointer to execute operations, and observeOn is a pointer to thread that result of execution function is return. 
Btw sorry for my English

Comment: Because `delay` has its own scheduler that will change the thread so having an `observeOn` just before that has no practical effect.

Comment: if i good understood, the problem was that delay hadnt  got a scheduler?

Comment: No. `delay` is very similar to `observeOn` and having them next to each other has no practical effect. Same as having two `observeOn`s right after the other.